# why size of the database increases in size when a full database backup is taken from a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Database 'DB' whose's size is 34 GB. Found By this

```
EXEC sp_helpdb @dbname= 'DB'
```

I restore a full database backup from the 'DB' with name 'newDB'.
I again the run the following SQL command.

```
   EXEC sp_helpdb @dbname= 'newDB'
```

It shows 5 GB. My question is why 45 GB? Why not 3 GB?

Answer (score 0):

The `sp_helpdb` procedure returns size of database files, which has very little correlation with the actual amount of data in them.

Try `sp_spaceused` instead.

Comment: I used sp_helpdb for both